# Rewriting reference from class to functional components, or: Not understanding the syntax

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using this library https://github.com/lhandel/react-native-card-flip#readme.
A reference to call a function is set like this

```
  <CardFlip style={styles.cardContainer} ref={(card) => this.card = card} >
    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.card} onPress={() => this.card.flip()} ><Text>AB</Text></TouchableOpacity>
    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.card} onPress={() => this.card.flip()} ><Text>CD</Text></TouchableOpacity>
  </CardFlip>
```

This implies that the example is used in a class component (because of the `this`).
I am using the component in a functional component and I am using it like so.

```
const Foo ({index}) => {
       useEffect(() => {
          this['card' + index].jiggle(...);
       }, []);


       return <CardFlip
           ref={card => (this['card' + index] = card)}
           ....>
      {...}
    </CardFlip>
}
```

For my understanding, this should not work. I cannot use `this` in a functional component. But then, this is not a `this` because it is missing the dot (`this.`). Weirdly, it is working and not throwing an error. However, what is the result of `this['card' + index]`? Why is `this['card' + index].jiggle(...);` working in the useEffect?

When I rewrite the `useEffect()` hook like so

```
useEffect(() => {
   setTimeout(() => this['card' + index].jiggle(JIGGLE_SETTINGS), 2000);
}, []);
```

I get

> TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating '_this['card' + index].jiggle')

So, how would I set the reference in a way, that I can include `index` in there AND use `setTimeout()`. I think I am missing something fundamental about references here...

Comment: No, `this` is always `this`.  Generally `this.x` is equivalent to `this["x"]`.

Comment: @Pointy aaaaah I did not know that... And why is that working in a functional comopnent then?

Comment: Well the `this` symbol always has *some* value. Depending  on how a function is called, it may be a reference to an object that has the function as the value of a property, or it may be a value supplied in a call to `.call()` or `.apply()` or `.bind()`, or it may be a default value (possibly `undefined`). But `this` is a reserved word that only does what the language rules say it does.

Comment: @Pointy ah okay, thanks. And why is this failing then `setTimeout(() => this['card' + index].jiggle(JIGGLE_SETTINGS), 2000);`?

Comment: When you use `=>` functions, the way `this` works changes. Instead of being set when the function is called, like a `function` function, an `=>` function uses the `this` in the environment where the function was created.

Comment: @Pointy ah okay. I would I assume changing the arrow function to a `function` would solve it, however this `setTimeout(function () { this['card' + index].jiggle(JIGGLE_SETTINGS)}, 2000);`  still failes.

Comment: Yes, because `setTimeout()` by itself does not preserve any relationship between an "interesting" object and a method. You can use `.bind()` to preserve that relationship; the topic of using object methods as event/timer handlers is a pretty common one in questions here.

Comment: @Pointy got it, thanks. Wanna post this as an answere? Because the current answere is only answering half what I asked for.

Answer (score 1):

The code is keeping a reference to the current card's DOM element as an instance property (`card`) using a computed ref (`ref={(card) => this.card = card}`) and then calling into the DOM element directly when it needs to flip (`this.card.flip()`).

The equivalent in a function component wouldn't be much different, but instead of saving the card on an instance property, you'd use a ref directly.

1. Create the ref: `const cardRef = useRef(null);`
2. Ensure it's set to the element: `ref={cardRef}`
3. Use it to call `flip`: `onPress={() => cardRef.current.flip()}`

```
const Example = () => {
    const cardRef = useRef(null);
    return (
        <CardFlip style={styles.cardContainer} ref={cardRef}>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.card} onPress={() => cardRef.current.flip()}>
                <Text>AB</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.card} onPress={() => cardRef.current.flip()}>
                <Text>CD</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </CardFlip>
    );
};
```

---

We can avoid constantly updating the functions we're passing to `TouchableOpacity` (which *might* [might] help it avoid rerendering), since they don't close over anything that changes:

```
const Example = () => {
    const cardRef = useRef(null);
    const flip = useCallback(() => cardRef.current.flip(), [cardRef]);
    return (
        <CardFlip style={styles.cardContainer} ref={cardRef}>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.card} onPress={flip}>
                <Text>AB</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.card} onPress={flip}>
                <Text>CD</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </CardFlip>
    );
};
```

We don't technically need `cardRef` in the dependency array because refs never change (only their `current` property changes), but it doesn't matter and I tend to prefer it...